# Cursor returns a count of -1, but items are present?

Tags: android

I am using an SQLite database to store and retreive my app data, and what to check for duplicate entries. I attempt to retrieve all entries where the titles match, as such:

```
Cursor c = mDb.query(DatabaseHelper.GOALS_TABLE_NAME, 
                     new String[] { Goals.GOAL_ID, Goals.TITLE }, 
                     Goals.TITLE + "='" + title + "'", null, null, null, 
                     null, null);
```

where title is the one to compare against.

This query runs, but the cursor gives a count of -1. A call without the where clause also returns -1, but I know data is present, as I am able to bind a list view to it.

Is there something I am missing, do I have to populate the cursor somehow?

Thanks in advance,

Venatu

Comment: You say you're able to bind a ListView to it. Do you also see some items in that ListView then?

Comment: Yes, all the items I expect appear. I am setting the list view as shown in the notepad tutorial. (Tried to post the code, but came out unformatted)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you do a `query()`, the `Cursor` is returned immediately. The query itself is not yet run. Only when you do something that requires a data load will the query be executed. Try executing another method first (e.g., `moveToFirst()`) before calling `getCount()` and see if that changes things.

Comment: I see, this is the reason why my cursor size returned 0 but upon invoking getCount when I put the result into the logger it works. That is very neat explanation thanks!